# Inactive language version visits on Sitecore 9.3 website and potential security implications

Tags: security, language-fallback

Recently, we received a website visit report indicating a significant number of non-existent language versions visits on our Sitecore 9.3 website (see to the image below).

[image]

We have only enabled the English version, so we are concerned whether these records are a result of external tools attacking our site or if this is a normal occurrence. This issue started occurring since last month.

We would greatly appreciate guidance on how to prevent such occurrences and ensure the security of our website. Please provide any advice or recommendations you may have.

What is the recommended approach for handling inactive language versions on Sitecore 9.3? Currently, when accessing an inactive language version, it returns an empty header using the default layout, which is not considered best practice. Please provide guidance on how to handle this situation appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, when there is no language version, `404 Page Not Found` status should be returned.

Long long time ago I wrote a blog post with sample code which sets `Sitecore.Context.Item` to `null` if the item doesn't have language version.

You can find it in wayback machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150324234154/http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/sitecore-displaying-pages-without-a-language-version/

In shortcut - register your processor after `ItemResolver` or some other custom item resolvers that you have in your application:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.ItemLaguageVersionValidator, MyAssembly" />
```

And in the code check number of versions in current language like that:

```
public class ItemLaguageVersionValidator : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        // don't change the flow of Experience Editor or Preview mode
        if (!Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
            return;

        if (Context.Item != null 
            && Context.Item.Paths.IsContentItem
            && Context.Item.Versions.Count == 0)
        {
            Log.Info($"Not existing language '{Context.Item.Language}' request for item '{Context.Item.Paths.FullPath}'", this);
            Context.Item = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marek Musielak, Massive thanks for your detailed reply and will have a try.